# Need tips on creating a custom usb cable

Tags: usb, shielding, gauge

In short, I have two questions:

1. Does shielding matter for a USB2.0 cable inside a computer? The length is about 50 cm.
2. Is the requirement that data wires should be thicker than data ones still valid if a USB device has a separate power source?

I have two devices (a water pump and an argb controller) supplied with USB 2.0 cables for connecting directly to a MB. Both devices are powered through sata. My MB has a single USB header, which is just enough to connect 2 devices. The simplest way would be just to plug the devices to the MB directly, but in the name of handiness and aesthetic I'd like to make an intermediate cable. Firstly, I made a cable putting 4 x 26 AWG wires (for power) and 4x 28 AWG (for data) into a paracord sleeve and it looked good until I realized that it missed shielding. Given the length of the cable about 50 cm, I am not sure that shielding might be neglected. Am I right?
As a second option I found a shielded cable with 8 x 28 AWG wires inside on the local market. With that I could make a shielded USB cable for my needs, but then the power wires would be as thin as data ones. My guess is that with a separate power source it is not an issue, but I'd like to be sure.
I would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Not only are you missing shielding - you're missing the correct & consistent characteristic impedance. At USB speeds, *everything* is a transmission line. Simply Hooking D+ to D+ and D- to D- is not enough.

Comment: Use the USB cable types designed for internal use. MOBO to front panel,

Comment: @brhans Small nitpick: hooking D+ to D+ and D- to D- without shielding or proper impedance for such a short run is *probably* okay for USB 1.1 low speed, but 1.1 full speed, 2.0 high speed, and *absolutely* 3.x superspeed will definitely not work. So you might be able to use a keyboard over that link, but you can forget about hooking up a printer or a flash drive.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I suppose that at least the water pump would send a more or less significant amount of data to the PC and so having a good cable is a must. I looked deeper into how a USB cable works and with that knowledge I decided that making a DIY cable is not a thing that I could handle at home :) Will look for a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are making a custom MB to 2 X USB cable.
There is a pinout diagram for a usb 2 mb header here.
https://www.dell.com/community/Optiplex-Desktops/745-MT-HR330-motherboard-USB-2-0-header/td-p/7302534

I would use shielded cable and 6 X cable.

Shield can connect to ground for both. Important if the devices have power supply separate.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that the shield and the ground wires might be connected to each other, now I know for sure :)